# ValueError: time data '14.07.13 15:01' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'

Tags: python

```
datetime.strptime('14.07.13 15:01', "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M").date()

ValueError: time data '14.07.13 15:01' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я не пайтонист, но обычно Y - это 4 цифры года

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior - там большая табличка с форматами и %Y - это 4 цифры. %y - две. Даже если у вас год < 1000 - все равно 4 цифры и год нужно дополнить нулями. Например, 0098

Comment: %y - решилось этим, сенк

Answer (score 1):

Формат для `strptime()` и `strftime()` - описан на [этой странице документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). В частности там есть пояснения по поводу директив `%y` и `%Y` (обратите внимание, регистр имеет значение!)

`%y` - это год без указания столетия. Год двумя цифрами - 91, 17, 02, 05.

`%Y` - год с указанием столетия - 1991, 2017, 1802, 2005.

Если у вас год < 1000, то вы должны дополнить его нулями так, чтобы он занимал 4 цифры (0053, 0099). С двух символьным точно так же (05, 00, 09).

Также в версии 3.6 была добавлена директива `%G`, которая означает год 4 цифрами (аналог `%Y`). Однако, это значение *мутное* и относится к стандарту ISO 8601. В этом формате первая неделя в году начинается с первого понедельника той недели в году, в которой есть хотя 4 дня. Звучит жутко, но вот пример - 1 января 2010 - это пятница, а значит согласно этому стандарту пятница, суббота и воскресенье относятся к 53 неделе 2009 года, а первая неделя 2010 начинается с 4 января. Это все относится только к подсчету номеров недели и не делает 2010 год 2009-ым. Также эта директива совсем не то же самое, что `%Y` и они не взаимозаменяемы и несовместимы.